# Flexbox with unexpected whitespace at top

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an issue with a flexbox not filling up all the way to my navbar, I cannot for the life of me figure it out and a negative margin does absolutely nothing

Here's a screenshot

[image: a busy cat]

```css
.hero {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1500?random");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.hero>.center-content {
  width: 400px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.hero>.center-content h1,
.center-content h3 {
  color: white;
  line-height: 1;
}

.hero>.center-content h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.hero>.center-content h3 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.center-content>.button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.center-content>.button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  color: #006594;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="heroImage">
  <div class="hero">
    <div class="center-content">
      <h1>Lazris</h1>
      <h3>Revive Your Web Presence</h3>
      <a href="#" class="button">Some Action Here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have not provided the code for your navigation bar, so currently there is no whitespace!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the margin top on your active menu

```
.nav > .active {
    /** margin-top: 10px; Remove **/
}
```

Comment: Where is that rule `.nav > .active {` available in the question?

Comment: Which mean, when that link dies, both this answer and question is useless for future users, as the issue causing it is not will never be accessible any more. That is a really bad way of answer a question, so down vote from me. If the OP update the question so this answer is meaningful, notify me and I'll retract my down vote